# Java gravity bug

Tags: java, game-physics

Im having a problem with my gravity class it should change the y coordinate until it reaches the base whenever the user jumps but when I press the jump button (W) repeatedly it bugs and the cube keeps going down under the base.

main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame implements Runnable{ //main class

    static Panel panel;
    static Frame frame;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    Frame(){ //constructor

        super("Game Frame");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        panel = new Panel();

        add(panel);

    } //constructor

    public static void main (String args[]){ //main method

        frame = new Frame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Thread T1 = new Thread(frame);
        T1.start();

    } //main method


    public void run(){ //run method

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){ //key listener method

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) { //key pressed

                switch(arg0.getKeyChar()){

                //A (LEFT)
                case 'a':
                    panel.x -= 10;
                    panel.repaint();break;

                //D (RIGHT)
                case 'd':
                    panel.x += 10;
                    panel.repaint();break;

                //W (UP)
                case 'w':
                    panel.y -= 40;
                    panel.repaint();
                    Thread T1 = new Thread(new Gravity());
                    T1.start();

                } //switch

            } //key pressed method

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

        }); //key listener method
    } //run method
} //main class
```

Panel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Panel extends JPanel{ //class

    static BufferedImage bg;
    static int x = 20;
    static int y = 195;


    //PAINT METHOD
    public void paint(Graphics g){ //method

        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //IMPORTING IMAGES
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Background.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //DRAWING GAME
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0,500,275,null);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);

    } //method




} //class
```

Gravity class:

```
public class Gravity implements Runnable{ //class

    @Override
    public void run() { //run method

            while(Frame.panel.y != 195){ //while loop

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { //catch exception
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //catch exception

                Frame.panel.y += 5;
                Frame.panel.repaint();

            } //while loop

    } //run method

} //class
```

Comment: Put this in a debugger, or write out println statements to determine what's going on. People here are happy to answer specific questions, but less happy to just take a set of code and debug it for you.

Comment: Okay thanks arcy . I tried solving it for a long time thats why I tried posting this here. Is there any way I can use something like a trace table in java? As the syntax is alright its just some sort of a logical error

Comment: You don't seem to show the interesting parts either. Where is `Gravity` used? My recommendation is to skip `Thread`s all together if you don't really know how they work. The simplest way to create simulation is just to `paint`, `doPhysics`, `paint`, `doPhysics` etc. interleaved.

Comment: There's the entire code up their so yeah i show where gravity is used . You're right tho i dont really know how threads work as nearly everything above is self thaught. I used the threads instead of paint-pysichs-paint-pysichs so that the user can still move (A/D) on the X axis and even jump higher while falling which wont work without multi threading as the program will run the gravity method and ignore any inputs until it is finished

Comment: My mistake -- I didn't see the implementation of `run`. Use the @ to notify me on your comments. As said though, I still recommend removing all `Thread`s. I also recommend you remove the `Gravity` class. Instead, just add `panel.y += 5` somewhere in your `Frame.run` function.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should not create multiple Threads, rather reuse one. What may happen is that two theads modify Frame.panel.y. The first moves it to 195 while the second is sleeping, then the second moves it to 200 and your !=195 condition is met. Crashing happens by painting outside your frame later. A simple work around would be to replace "while(Frame.panel.y != 195)" by "while(Frame.panel.y < 195)"

Comment: Thanks Martin G . I understood your reasoning and I agree but it didnt work anyways . I tried changing the logical operator to < and it still did the same and then I tried removing the thread for the main program and the program gave me some sort of runtime error when trying to move the cube